# How to use systemd-boot instead of GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, uefi, dkms

I have Kubuntu 21.10 installed and I want to use systemd-boot instead of GRUB. I am aware of [another ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225791/how-to-replace-grub-with-bootloader-systemd-boot-in-ubuntu-20-04) but it does not mention anything about dkms modules. The original guide mentions that a deviation of the guide is needed for users with dkms modules, but does not mention what to change:

> Note: We can get away with one script in three places because we don't
> have anything special going on during the build, but if you have
> initramfs PREREQs, special firmware/dkms build tasks, are stuck
> running a version of run-parts that demands /bin/sh compatibility, or
> want to do other fun and wonderful things like mirror the entire EFI
> partition to another location for safety, you'll need to deviate from
> this tutorial a little bit.

How can I use systemd-boot and configure it properly for my dkms modules? (I don't have dual boot)

Comment: What special DKMS moduls do you have? Have you tried following the guide?

Comment: The realtek RTL8821CE dkms driver. I could not afford getting any downtime for the time being, I will try when I can. @sup

Comment: I think it might turn out it works out just fine for you. Basically I think that if you do not have any special scripts hooked into installing a new kernel image, you should be fine in this regard.